Film roll or a photograph is the key to solve the crime
I watched a movie years back. Somewhere around 1995-1998, when I was 11 or 13 years old and now I am 32. They played this movie on our local channel in Malaysia. I went to bed with full of surprises and was wondering how could the story writer could come up with such plot and twist in the story. It was such a brilliant movie. 
The movie is about a crime / murder which was filmed and the roll was hidden somewhere or went missing so they needed the (film roll / the video / the photo) to solve the case and to catch the criminal.
For some reason I registered the name of the film as 'Stranger' in my head when I go to bed that night after watching the movie. Until now I couldn't figure out which movie is that, it's killing me not knowing the movie. It's not Rear window or 8mm.

I'm afraid this is a rather common trope. Do you remember anything else about the plot? Specific scenes? The actors or characters? Was it American? What were the actual twists or surprises in this film?

I cant remember anything else. It was 20 years ago. If i knew who's actor or actress I could have track down the movie in IMDB. I thought, someone could help me figure out the movie with these clues I've given. Can't be that many movie where the 8mm film roll or a photograph is the only proof of crime right?

Could it be 'blow out'. With John travolta. That film has him trying to prove an assassination after his recording is stolen from his sound recording studio.


This could be BLOW-UP (1966), a British film by Italian director Michaelangelo Antonioni. (The film BLOW OUT (1981) with John Travolta is an American remake where there is a sound recording of the murder instead of photographs.) David Hemmings plays a London photographer with a wild lifestyle who normally photographs models. He is attracted to a woman and follows her to a park. He secretly takes photos of her and a man who may be her lover. The woman did not want to be photographed, so he swaps the roll of film with another and gives it back to her. 
After developing the photos, he discovers that he has also photographed a dead body. Unfortunately, he cannot find the body on a return trip to the park. To make matters worse, someone breaks into his apartment and steals all of the photos and negatives except one. Now he can never prove that a murder has even occurred.
